# elasticsearch downloadable manual

Tags: elasticsearch

Does anyone know where I can find a downloadable manual (any format) for elasticsearch? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/ is OK, but sometimes the site is not reachable, and searching for content is not practical.

Answer (score 6):

Not that I am aware of. You can fork and run the site locally if you have problems with it not being reachable which btw never happens for me. It is available on github: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/docs

Answer (score 2):

Cloning the repo is useless. You cannot build their docs since the asciidoc files for the build --all command are access protected.

The only solution is to crawl their site, for example with wget:

```
wget -r -l1 --page-requisites -N --convert-links -E robots=off "https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/index.html"
```

the index.html contains all the links of the doc subdirectories, so you can specify `-l1` which will make wget crawl only one level deep

note that you cannot use the search function on crawled docs since there is no server running in the background

Comment: cd /path/to/es_doc, then run download command, 
wget -c -r -np -k -L -p -l1 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/index.html
, create a soft link with, 

ln -s /path/to/es_doc/www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/index.html index.html index.html, finally you can play es docs with open index.html at local.

Answer (score 1):

Semi related and perhaps helpful - ES docs are available as a [DocSet](https://kapeli.com/dash#docsets) for the [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash) MacOS and iOS app for offline docs. May or may not be useful but I find it great for travel. It cost $ but can be used for free as well.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the GitHub repo for all the documentation for their products: 
 https://github.com/elastic/docs

Please note the following disclaimer in the repo:

```
Conditions of use
This documentation build process is provided to the public purely for the
purpose of testing documentation changes before submitting pull requests to
the appropriate Elasticsearch repository.

The documents produced by this build process may be published only on 
http://www.elastic.co. They may not be published in any other form or on
any other website without explicit permission.
```